# Preventing child click event from triggering its parent event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, events, video

I have a video tag which is placed inside an asp.net LinkButton control. The button fires some event when clicked. If the user clicks the video, both the video event (playing the video) and the button event fire. I only want the video to play.

I found different solutions on the web, but they didn't work.

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       function play(e)
        {
            if (!e) var e = window.event;
            e.cancelBubble = true;
            if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
        }

        /*$(".pVideo").click(function (event) {
            if (event.target == this) {
                event.stopPropagation(); 
            }
        });*/

    </script>
```

This is the video tag which is placed inside a LinkButton (it's placed inside a label, but I think that's not a problem because a label has no onclick event):

```
  <asp:Label runat="server" Visible="false" ID="videoHolder">
                        <video controls="true" id="pVideo" onclick="play()">
                            <source  src='<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("postVideo2").ToString()) ? "/uploadedVideos/" + Eval("postVideo2"): "" %>' type="video/mp4"/> 

                        </video>
               </asp:Label>
```

When calling play function I get this error in JS: "no element found", but I couldn't figure out the reason. Please notice that I also tried the commented JQuery function after adding the required resources, but I kept getting error saying that $ is not defined.

**Edit**: This is how I did it for JQuery, but still not working:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js">



        $("#pVideo").click(function () {
            if (event.target == this) {
                event.stopPropagation(); 
            }
        });

    </script>
```

Video tag:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Visible="false" ID="videoHolder">
                        <video controls="true" id="pVideo">
                            <source  src='<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("postVideo2").ToString()) ? "/uploadedVideos/" + Eval("postVideo2"): "" %>' type="video/mp4"/> 

                        </video>
```

I'm getting "no element found" error.

Can anyone please tell me how to play the video without firing the parent LinkButton event?

Thanks.

Comment: The event object is not passed via online handlers automatically, and all browsers don't implement global event object.

Comment: @Teemu, thanks, but I didn't get your point. Can you please elaborate more? What's causing the problem, and what can be the solution?

Comment: You're using jQuery, get rid of the inline event handler completely

Comment: `e` in `play` is `undefined` in some browsers, despite of you're trying to detect its existence. The best fix would be to do what adeneo has suggested.

Comment: @adeneo, thanks I've used that, but it keeps saying $ not defined. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: @Teemu, thanks for providing this info, so I will try to work with jquery, it looks better.

Comment: If `$` is not defined, you're not including jQuery properly

Comment: @adeneo, thanks, I fixed that but now I'm getting element not found error, can you please check the question again I've updated it. Thank you.

Comment: Add `document.ready`

Comment: @adeneo, thanks but that didn't work either, what can be causing this?

Comment: As far as I can see you are putting the video inside the label tag? The label seems to have Visible="false" set. Also for the ID problem inspect and check the ClientIDMode setting for the application and see what do you have as id for this element in your output.

Comment: @AgopDogramadzhiyan, thanks, yes it's set to false that will be changed from code behind and it's working very well. As I know ClientIDMode is only for asp.net controls does that apply to the html video tag?